# Slim framework htaccess not able to redirect properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, mod-rewrite, slim

I have 3 files which contain my web services.
Files are index.php, message.php, schedule.php

And my htaccess file code is below:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^ schedule.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^ messages.php [QSA]
```

When I run my web service "http://192.168.1.139/projects/interlinx-api/v1/profile" which is available in index.php file my web service run successfully.

But when I run my web service "http://192.168.1.139/projects/interlinx-api/v1/my-calendar" which is available in schedule.php file my web service not worked. It gives me **404 Not found** error.

Same as messages.php file when I run api in this file then it gives me **404 Not found** error.

Also one thing when I changed sequence of files means when I added schedule.php file on first position api worked nicely in schedule.php file.

Help me to write correct htaccess file.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: What are you expecting these rewrite rules to match?

Comment: Where is I am wrong? Could you tell me.

Comment: You only need a single "Front Controller" like index.php. [Tutorial](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2)

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel0 said, you only need one "FrontController", mostly `index.php`.
There you should create routes matching your urls.

Your `.htaccess` file should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA]
```